Yup validation for date and time
How can i combine sendTimeTime and sendTimeDate to get a single DateTime and validate using yup such that it can not be less than current datetime of client browser. I am using material ui date and time picker, and other components and default react form.
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Controller
                name='sendTimeDate'
                control={control}
                rules={{ required: true }}
                render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
                  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                    <DatePicker
                      defaultValue={dayjs()}
                      onChange={onChange}
                      
                    />
                  </LocalizationProvider>
                )}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Controller
                name='sendTimeTime'
                control={control}
                rules={{ required: true }}
                render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
                  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                    {' '}
                    <TimePicker
                      value={value}
                      onChange={onChange}
                     
                    />
                  </LocalizationProvider>
                )}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

